# Разные версии android и значение item в onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

Tags: android

Помогите решить проблему. Есть список меню, при нажатии на тот или иной элемент списка выполняем какое то действие.

В разных версиях android item.toString() имеет разные значения.
В android 2.2 - содержит название пункта меню. Например "Настройки"
А начиная с 4 версии - содержит уже вот такое "com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapper@416ef928", соответственно условие не работает

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   Log.d("myTag",item.toString());
   if(item.toString().equals("Настройки")){

         //Какой то код  
   }

    return true;
}
```

Дело в том это элементы меню берутся не их XML. Вот как я их делаю(использую ActionBarSherlock)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("Мое меню");//Описание меню
    subMenu1.add("Настройки");

    MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
    subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_overflow);//Иконка меню
    subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно про то, какие входные параметры может принимать метод [`add`][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 2):

Пользуйтесь определением действия по id.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_add: {
         ...
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

а в меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:title="@string/action_add"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Опередили, ё-моё...)

Comment: @SuperCreeper - ![alt text][2]

  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/8queCgI.png